# Three.js: PointLight change distance

Tags: three.js, distance, lighting

I have made a scene with three.js in which I make use of a PointLight.

```
var distance = 10000;
var intensity = 10;
var decay = 0;
var hex = 0xFFFFFF;
var light1 = new THREE.PointLight(hex, intensity, distance, decay);
```

I want to use shadows, so I added

```
light1.shadow.camera.near = 200;
light1.shadow.camera.far = 10000;
light1.shadow.camera.fov = 90;
light1.shadow.bias = -0.00022;
light1.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
light1.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
```

Until here everything worked perfect. However, as soon as I include in the next line:

```
light1.castShadow = true;
```

Then the distance visibly changes from `10000` to `1000`.
If I call the distance from `light1` to the console, it is still `10000`.
 Even though it is not like that in the canvas.
(I have changed it to a ~50-digit number with no change in distance)

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a shadow via `THREE.Texture()`, in this way the shadow will be an independent element and shouldn't influence the position of the `PointLight`.

```
var shadowTexture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
shadowTexture.needsUpdate = true;
var shadowMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: shadowTexture, opacity: 0.5});
var shadowGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(100, 100, 100, 1);

// Locate the position of the shadows
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(shadowGeo, shadowMaterial);
mesh.position.y = 0;
mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
scene.add( mesh );
```

I am applying the shadow to a `PlaneGeometry` since I assume that the shadow is casted on the scene. In any case, give also a look at [this example](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Shadow.html) concerning shadows in a scene.